Prevent or detect scrolling by dragging of scroll indicator
In our app, we display a large list of items (roughly 30000 items) whereby each item needs to convert a complex/long string with tags into a NSAttributedString which is then displayed. We have optimised this conversion as good as it gets, however, if the user scrolls a huge distance by grabbing the scroll indicator of the ScrollView, the app freezes completely as hundreds of items need to be "calculated" simultaneously (only to then not being shown as the user has already scrolled further).
Thus, is there a way to disable just this "grab to scroll" behaviour while maintaining the scroll indicators visible (hence, using .scrollIndicators(.hidden) isn't an option)? Thanks!
ScrollView{
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(1..<200, id:\.self) { item in
                Text(String(item))
                // Text(getAttributedStringForItem(item) // ⚠️ NOTE: In the real application, a time-consuming operation is performed here in order to generate a preview for the item. This operation cannot be run on a background thread (a string with tags is converted to a NSAttributedString – an operation which must be run on the main thread).
            }
        }
    }

Edit: As someone rightly pointed out in the comments, it would be against the user's expectations to show the scroll indicators while disabling the scrolling by grabbing them. Hence, I wonder if there's a way to detect such scrolling (so that we could disable the generation of the previews during the time of scrolling)?

Imagine for a moment that you had a sheet that had .presentationDragIndicator(.visible) but dragging on it would not close the sheet. Wouldn't that be confusing or even irritating for the user? I'd argue the same for the scroll indicators. With them being visible comes the expectation for the user to drag them if needed, unless there is some other visual indication that dragging is not possible. So even if you implemented a custom indicator that used something like Geometry reader, it should not merely look like a normal scrollbar indicator. Just some food for thought.

That's a good point. Thanks @AndreiG. Our entire app sticks to Apple's design guidelines and this indeed would be an ugly exception. I guess we should search for a way to optimise our conversion code even more!
On another note, if I delete this question, would you lose my upvote on your comment (if so, I would not delete it!)?

I don't think you should delete the question. It's a very valid question and you should leave it for anyone else who may look to achieve something similar.

Thanks, @AndreiG. I've slightly adjusted to question so that is ask for a way to detect such scrolling (so that we could disable the generation of previous during the scroll).

It would be helpful if your example included a reproduction of the issue, otherwise I am not sure how it could be tested by others. As an idea, the only thing that grabbing the indicators changes from simply scrolling is that you can drag faster (and cover a greater scrolling distance). So maybe you can use that as the logic to disable preview generation - if scroll distance is larger than a certain amount, disable preview generation.

Thanks, neat idea. I'll look into your suggestion and post an update (which might take several weeks, since we have a bunch of urgent issues to deal with first). As to the reproducible example, there's really nothing more to add. I have, however, added a note to the above code, explaining that a slow preview-generation operation is run which must be run on the main thread.
